# Opening an attached pdf file on wiki page outside of browser

Tags: pdf

I have set up a personal wiki on a localhost using drupal. I have attached pdf's that open in the browser window which is generally ok but I'd rather be able to open them in Preview so I get all the usability benefits of that app (without downloading them and thus creating a 2nd version outside the wiki directory). Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Since you´re working on a localhost: are the links to the PDFs http:// or file:// ? In the latter case I guess you should be able to get it to work..

Comment: Asmus links are http:// but I'll research that and see if I can't tweak something, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can open them in Preview without downloading them.  Also - by merely opening or viewing the document at all, you are actually downloading it.  It's stored in a temp directory somewhere, and likely trashed when you close your browser.